# 'Incorrect arguments' thrown by bcrypt-nodejs - Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, passport.js

I have a log in system set up for my Node.js app. Recently I made a change to my user model (CoffeeScript):

```
password: String
```

to

```
password:
        type: String
        select: false
```

My function to compare password hashes with bcrypt is as follows:

```
userSchema.methods.validPassword = (password) ->
        bcrypt.compareSync password, @local.password
```

Now whenever I run the above function this error is thrown

```
Incorrect arguments
```

Anyone have any idea why this would be thrown after I add "select: false" to my user model?

Answer (score 0):

This is thrown if either password or @local.password is not a string. It just happened to me as I was trying to call the instance method on an instance that was not including @local.password in the loaded attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
userSchema.methods.validPassword = (password) ->
  bcrypt.compareSync password, @local.password
```

Assuming this is in a class, you'll need `=>` rather than `->` in order for `@local` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Log the values of both the saved password and the incoming password. My bet is that one of them is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

check if value for Password is getting populated.setting select false will not retrieve the value the password.